# When asking for a table Error occurs: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.166.80.90:443 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-table-storage

I try to connect to an azure-storage to change some data in a table. The connection to the azure cloud works but when I try to work with a table in there I get the time-out-Error.

I use node.js. We work behind a corporate proxy but there are some proxy-server one can use for special internet access. Thus, I got the connection to the azure-portal and I can create the tableService but I can not do anything with a table. Already the question 'doesTableExist' does not work. I also tried the function 'createTableIfNotExists' but same matter.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var storageName = "...";
var storageKey = "...";

var tableService = azure.createTableService( storageName, storageKey);

tableService.logger.level = azure.Logger.LogLevels.DEBUG;
console.log('TableService activ' + tableService);

tableService.doesTableExist('tblName', function(err, res) {
    if (!err) {
            console.log('res' + res.status);
        } else {
        console.log('Error at doesTableExists ' + err.stack);
    }
});
```

How can I get the table values? The Table exists.